# Python 3.6.1 why don't I receive UDP packets

Tags: python, networking

I have a server where I have a script which sends UDP packets to my ip address and I have a client script on my PC that receives UDP packets.

```
#python3.6.1

import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('myip', 49999))

data, address = sock.recvfrom(100)
print('Received {}'.format(data.decode('ascii')))
```

On the server side my scripts connects to ('myip', 49999) and starts sending packets.
I took my ip from ip4.me i tried to bind my socket to '0.0.0.0' too and i tried other ports nothing seems to work.

Comment: And your PC is not firewalled or UDP packets to port 49999 can pass the firewall? Same server side side: UDP packets can leave the server's network?

Answer (score 0):

If that is the server script, i guess it should have a while loop in it:

`while True:
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(100)
    print('Received {}'.format(data.decode('ascii')))`